# Install driver for GTX 1070?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I want to install the latest driver for my GTX 1070 (my monitor flickers sometimes and I think this might be because I never installed a proper driver).

Since NVIDIA supports Linux driver I downloaded the latest driver for my card at https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us.

I made the file executable and stated it from terminal

`sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.93.run`

However, I can't install it. It shows me the folloing message:

> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue?

When I enter yes, I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

THis is the log file:

> nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' creation
>   time: Fri Jan 25 15:49:58 2019 installer version: 410.93
>
> PATH:
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
>
> nvidia-installer command line:
>       ./nvidia-installer
>
> Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
>
> Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
>   -> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
>   -> Installing NVIDIA driver version 410.93.
>   -> Running distribution scripts    executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
>   -> done.
>   -> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation) ERROR: The
>   Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system.  This driver
>   is incompatible with the NVIDIA driver, and must be disabled before
>   proceeding.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README and your Linux
>   distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable
>   the Nouveau kernel driver.
>   -> For some distributions, Nouveau can be disabled by adding a file in the modprobe configuration directory.  Would you like nvidia-installer
>   to attempt to create this modprobe file for you? (Answer: No)

I'm not sure if it matters, but I did `apt-get upgrade` before and haven't restarted yet.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose the nvidia installer rather than the one in ubuntu repos?

Comment: @j-money how to install the one in ubuntu repos? Would you recommend that over the offical nvida driver?

Comment: IIRC `sudo apt-get install nvidia`?  I prefer to let whatever distro's package manager to what it does best, manage packages, for me.

Comment: @j-money this throws that the package nvide is not available

Comment: `nvide != nvidia`

Comment: @j-money yes sry typo from me. It  throws that the package nvidia is not available

Comment: See my answer it's not as simple as I wanted it to be

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First remove any nvidia packages you might have had laying around

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Add the repository to your repo list

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
```

And update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then enter the following

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

in terminal which gives the following output:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B81sv00001462sd00003302bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Now one may take the recommended driver from the list and installs it by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-415
```

---

Credits to j-money for 80% of this answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install the nvidia driver from the repos (unfortuanatley it doesn't seem to be as easy as I wanted it to be... :(  )

First remove any nvidia packages you might have had laying around

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Add the repository to your repo list

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
```

And update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the latest nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-XXX
```

Comment: Which number shout I replace `XXX` with?

Comment: According to https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html the latest version is 410.93 (which is by the way the one that I downloaded). When I replace `XXX` by 410 I get a prompt telling me that he cant find this package.

Comment: I did `ubuntu-drivers devices` which showed me that `nvidia-driver-415` was recommended. THen I could install it with `sudo apt install nvidia-diver-415`.

Comment: Was the last comment a question? Or an update? Also I don't keep track of the latest ubuntu drivers, so I will leave that as an exercise for you

Comment: To install, the command should be `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-xxx` to avoid the package not found error.